# TRIGGER в sql Server

Tags: sql-server, триггер

Можно ли сделать так что бы триггер после срабатывания выводил к примеру удалённый элемент автоматом, то есть после срабатывания триггер сразу запускается запрос к примеру `SELECT c_warehouse_id FROM counterparts`
Который выводить удалённый элемент или вставленный по такой же аналогии?

Вот такой триггер

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_tiger_test
ON WareHouse_DB.dbo.counterparts
AFTER DELETE  AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE
  @c_qty as INT,
  @c_warehouse_id as INT

  SELECT @c_qty = i.qty FROM deleted i;
  SELECT @c_warehouse_id = i.warehouse_id FROM deleted i;

  UPDATE warehouse
  SET warehouse.income_qty = warehouse.income_qty - @c_qty
  FROM Counterparts
  WHERE warehouse.id = @c_warehouse_id

  PRINT 'TRIGGER [delete_tiger_test] worked'

END
```

Если такое можно реализовать то как?

Comment: Выводит куда ? Не забывайте, что триггер работает на стороне БД. А у БД нет прямых средств общения с пользователем

Comment: @Mike Так мне и нужно что бы запрос выполнился автоматом без участия пользователя

Comment: @Mike На подобии `PRINT 'TRIGGER [delete_tiger_test] worked'` только что бы выводил запрос

Comment: @Mike Выводит в консоль

Comment: В какую консоль, у БД нет консоли. Консоль есть только у клиента, который работает с БД. А БД клиенту может возвращать только результат, который тот сам должен обработать и показать на консоли.

Comment: Хотя print в ms sql есть https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 он возвращает строку клиенту. А вот выведет ли ваш клиент его в консоль, это уже вопрос к используемому клиенту, а не к ms sql

Comment: @Mike А, такую автоматизацию вообще можно организовать но не триггером может?

Comment: Вы можете использовать в запросе предложение output, что бы он вернул обработанные строки, как обычный select. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Mike Спасибо! Попробую!